# Distributed computing in NodeJS - Mathematical expressions

Tags: node.js, distributed-computing, mathematical-expressions

I want to make a distributed system with many nodes that compute mathematical equations.

I was thinking about one "leader" as a gateway (similar to what eg. Apache does with distributed clustered websites) and many nodes. This leader will send work to nodes depending on which are not working.

My question is about the physical functionality of posting equations to nodes. Is there any npm module or well-known pattern to sending them?

I was thinking, that I will just send JSON formatted document filled with equations and data to nodes to compute, but this looks bulky to me.

Any other ideas? It would be awesome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could help you https://github.com/pioardi/ring-election , with this project you can divide your data in partitions and each node can take care of a partition range .
Let me know if you have questions